# Why is nginx complaining of an unknown directive?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to direct all HTTP requests resembling `/<uuid4>` to a specific HTTP server running on the localhost.  Below is the relevant `location` line in my nginx.conf:

```
location ~* "[0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}$" {  # matches UUIDv4
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass localhost:8000;
}
```

When starting nginx, I get the following error:  `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "8}-([0-9a-f]" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf:30`

What gives?

Comment: Isn't it `location [path] {...`? Looks like you have two tokens after _location_. I'm sure the docs would answer this, but you know, meh.

Comment: Syntax looks OK to me. Indeed adding `location ~* "[0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}$" {
        deny all;
}` to a standard config tests OK here. Perhaps a problem with quoting earlier in your config?